# Reading out a parameter from ffmpeg by using bash

Tags: bash, parameters, ffmpeg

I am having trouble with reading out a specific parameter from FFmpeg with bash. The parameter which I want to have, looks like this:

```
"FC_SOURCEFILE_MI_Audio_#1_Channel(s)"="1 channel"
"FC_SOURCEFILE_FC_location"="/content/flowcenter/highres/dokfest/dokfestftp8/Hands_Up_to_Heaven_prores1920x1080.mov"
```

and the second one is just there to confirm that it works properly

```
echo test: $FC_SOURCEFILE_MI_Audio_#1_Channel(s)
echo location: $FC_SOURCEFILE_FC_location
```

the outcome looks like this:

```
/home/mfc/ffmpeg/audio_pan.wav.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/mfc/ffmpeg/audio_pan.wav.sh: line 1: `echo test: $FC_SOURCEFILE_MI_Audio_#1_Channel(s)'
```

and by using the second command I get this outcome:

```
test: /content/flowcenter/highres/dokfest/dokfestftp8/Hands_Up_to_Heaven_prores1920x1080.mov
```

So my first guess was that my script does not like special characters and I looked up ASCII for `#`, `(`, `)` telling me 35 for #, 28 for (, 29 for ) but I am not sure how to write this in my bash-file. The only thing that came to my mind was typing in `"35"`, `"28"` and `"29"` but that did not work. What am I missing?

Comment: The only characters that the bash shell recognises for a variable name are alphanumerics and underscores - you can't have a variable named `$FC_SOURCEFILE_MI_Audio_#1_Channel(s)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use special characters in variable names. It'll save you allot of headaches. Such characters include parenthesis, curly braces, bang, and pound.

If you remove them from your variable declarations, your echo statements should work just fine

Comment: Thanks pal, I thought there was an easier way to work around this problem, but it looks like there is no easier way.